# How can I make this test passes? Method “dive” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

I've started using jest and enzyme recently.
I'm writing simple code to learn jest & enzyme.

There is one test I can't pass. I've had this problem for a long time.

I don't understand why the first assertion below is okay while the second assertion below is not.

```
expect(component.find(CommentBox).dive().find('.comment-box').exists()).toBe(true);

expect(component.find(CommentList).dive().find('.comment-list').exists()).toBe(true);
```

These components are siblings.

```
<div>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <CommentBox />
    <CommentList />
</div>
```

Could anyone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Here are all related codes and log.

## Test Result Log

```
FAIL  src/__tests__/components/App.test.js

● App › shows a comment list
Method “dive” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead.

at ShallowWrapper.single (node_modules/enzyme/build/ShallowWrapper.js:1516:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (src/__tests__/components/App.test.js:38:57)
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>
```

## App.test.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';

import App from '../../components/App';
jest.unmock('../../components/App');

import CommentBox from '../../components/CommentBox';
import ConnectedCommentList, { CommentList } from '../../components/CommentList';


describe('App', () => {

    let component;

    beforeEach(() => {
        component = shallow(<App />);
    });

    //This test passes!
    it('shows a comment box', () => {

        expect(component.find(CommentBox).dive().find('.comment-box').exists()).toBe(true);

    });

    //This test fails!!
    it('shows a comment list', () => {

        expect(component.find(CommentList).dive().find('.comment-list').exists()).toBe(true);

    })

});
```

## App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import CommentBox from './CommentBox';
import CommentList from './CommentList';

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Hello World!</div>
                <CommentBox />
                <CommentList />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

## CommentList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const propTypes = {};
const defaultProps = {};

export const CommentList = (props) => {

    const list = props.comments.map((comment) => {

        return <li key={comment}>{comment}</li>
    });

    return (
        <ul className="comment-list">
            {list}
        </ul>
    )

};

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        comments: state.comments
    }
}

CommentList.propTypes = propTypes;
CommentList.defaultProps = defaultProps;

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CommentList);
```

## Additional Info

I'm using shallow method instead of mount method because if I use mount method, then I get this error `Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(CommentList)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(CommentList)".`
 instead.

## JSX of CommentBox

```
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="comment-box">
            <textarea
                value={this.state.comment}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <button action="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

## JSX of CommentList

```
    <ul className="comment-list">
        {list}
    </ul>
```

## UPDATE!

```
it('shows a comment list', () => {
    console.log(component.debug());
})
```

I used debug method to see what enzyme is rendering.
This is the result.

```
<div>
  <div>
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <CommentBox />
  <Connect(CommentList) />
</div>
```

It seems that the problem occurs because it renders `<Connect(CommentList)>` instead of `<CommentList>`.

```
import ConnectedCommentList, { CommentList } from '../../components/CommentList';
```

But, in App.test.js, I import both ConnectedCommentList and regular CommentList and for the test, I use CommentList.

How can I make this test passes!?

Comment: What does your CommentBox look like?

Comment: @D-reaper Thank you for your responce! I edited my post and added the jsx of CommentBox & CommentList on the bottom of my post. Thanks!

Comment: does it work if you use `component.find('CommentList').dive()`

Comment: @AndreasKöberle I tried wrapping CommentList with single quotes but I got the same error message in my test.

Comment: Seems the problem is that `CommentList` is wrapped into redux `connect`. Will provide a solution after lunch.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle Yes! Yes! Exactly! I've just noticed it and updated my post! Please take a look at what I added on the bottom of my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `CommentList` is a Higher Order Component, so when enzyme renders it with shallow, it does not render the real `CommentList` but the wrapped one, and as `shallow` does not render children of a component, `find` will not be able to get this element either by a string nor by the constructor. The easiest way to fix this is by using `enzyme.mount` as this will force the component to render its children as well.

Or you use `ConnectedCommentList` to find the element:

```
it('shows a comment list', () = > {
  expect(component.find(ConnectedCommentList).dive().find('.comment-list').exists()).toBe(true);
})
```

Comment: import ConnectedCommentList, { CommentList } from '../../components/CommentList';

Comment: In App.test.js, I import CommentList that is not HOC and use it for test. How come when I run component.debug(), it renders   <Connect(CommentList) />!? Should it render <CommentList> ?

Comment: Cause in App you use the default export. I've update my answer for a simpler solution

Comment: I changed to this.
expect(component.find(ConnectedCommentList).dive().find('.comment-list').exists()).toBe(true);
Then, I got this error instead.
Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(CommentList)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(CommentList)".
I don't think I can write something like this. 'expect(component.find(<ConnectedCommentList store={store})'